# twitter user timeline does not get me any entity data

Tags: php, api, twitter, timeline

I am having problem with the user timeline in twitter, it does not provide me any data of entity. While with the same parameters if i try to fetch data of home timeline all the tweets come up with some entity data if any. 
Can anybody help in this.

Here is the code

```
 $Twitter->setToken($AccessToken, $TwitterSecret);
        $ie = true;
        $TwitterUser = $Twitter->get_accountVerify_credentials();
        $TwitterID = $TwitterUser->id;
        $Tweets = $Twitter->get_statusesHome_timeline(array('user_id' => $TwitterID, 'count' => $Count, 'include_entities' => $ie));
        $TwitterData = $Tweets->response;
```

This code shows no data of entity, as written in twitter documentation.

Comment: Can you show some actual code, please? Otherwise it's difficult to guess what's wrong.